# XCode 4 compiling is very slow, from where we can see compiling log?

Tags: gcc, xcode4

Using GCC 4.2 to compile project, very slow, from where I can see compiling log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left-hand pane is called the "Navigator". The buttons at the top include the Log Navigator. This is where your build logs (as well as run, test, etc.) are stored. You can view the log as the build is performed as well.